# Reading numbers inline

Tags: haskell, io-monad

Imagine I read an input block via stdin that looks like this:

```
3
12
16
19
```

The first number is the number of following rows. I have to process these numbers via a function and report the results separated by a space.

So I wrote this main function:

```
main = do         
    num <- readLn
    putStrLn $ intercalate " " [ show $ myFunc $ read getLine | c <- [1..num]]
```

Of course that function doesn't compile because of the `read getLine`.

But what is the correct (read: the Haskell way) way to do this properly? Is it even possible to write this function as a one-liner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it even possible to write this function as a one-liner?

Well, it is, and it's kind of concise, but see for yourself:

```
main = interact $ unwords . map (show . myFunc . read) . drop 1 . lines
```

So, how does this work?

1. `interact :: (String -> String) -> IO ()` takes all contents from STDIN, passes it through the given function, and prints the output.
2. We use `unwords . map (show . myFunc . read) . drop 1 . lines :: String -> String`:

   1. `lines :: String -> [String]` breaks a string at line ends.
   2. `drop 1` removes the first line, as we don't actually need the number of lines.
   3. `map (show . myFunc . read)` converts each `String` to the correct type, uses `myFunc`, and then converts it back to a `String.
   4. `unwords` is basically the same as `intercalate " "`.

However, keep in mind that `interact` isn't very GHCi friendly.

Comment: Nice! Why not replace `fmap` by `<$>`, though, in order to get rid of the outer parens?

Comment: @Jubobs: Because I'm still on GHC 7.8.x. And the default installed GHC in Ubuntu is ancient (7.6.3). This answer works with 7.4+ (maybe even earlier versions) without importing `Control.Applicative`, and I like to keep my answers somewhat backward compatible ;).

Comment: Fair enough. For my part, since `<$>` is part of the `Prelude`, I use it all the time.

Answer (score 2):

You can build a list of monadic actions with [`<$>`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-60--36--62-) (or `fmap`) and execute them all with [`sequence`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:sequence).

```
λ intercalate " " <$> sequence [show . (2*) . read <$> getLine | _ <- [1..4]]
1
2
3
4
"2 4 6 8"
```

Comment: Works nice in the ghci environment, but doesn't print anything compiled as a program: "putStrLn <$> intercalate " " <$> sequence [ show . myFunc . read <$> getLine | _ <- [1..num]]". It only works, when I bind this to a variable and print this variable in the next statement.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it even possible to write this function as a one-liner?

Sure, but there is a problem with the last line of your `main` function. Because you're trying to apply `intercalate " "` to

```hs
[ show $ myFunc $ read getLine | c <- [1..num]]
```

I'm guessing you expect the latter to have type `[String]`, but it is in fact not a well-typed expression. How can that be fixed? Let's first define

```hs
getOneInt :: IO Int
getOneInt = read <$> getLine
```

for convenience (we'll be using it multiple times in our code). Now, what you meant is probably something like

```hs
[ show . myFunc <$> getOneInt | c <- [1..num]]
```

which, if the type of `myFunc` aligns with the rest, has type `[IO String]`. You can then pass that to `sequence` in order to get a value of type `IO [String]` instead. Finally, you can "pass" that (using `=<<`) to

```
putStrLn . intercalate " "
```

in order to get the desired one-liner:

```hs
import Control.Monad ( replicateM )
import Data.List     ( intercalate )

main :: IO ()
main = do
    num  <- getOneInt
    putStrLn . intercalate " " =<< sequence [ show . myFunc <$> getOneInt | c <- [1..num]]
  where
    myFunc = (* 3) -- for example

getOneInt :: IO Int
getOneInt = read <$> getLine
```

In GHCi:

```
λ> main
3
45
23
1
135 69 3
```

Is the code idiomatic and readable, though? Not so much, in my opinion...

> [...] what is the correct (read: the Haskell way) way to do this properly?

There is no "correct" way of doing it, but the following just feels more natural and readable to me:

```hs
import Control.Monad ( replicateM )
import Data.List     ( intercalate )

main :: IO ()
main = do
    n  <- getOneInt
    ns <- replicateM n getOneInt
    putStrLn $ intercalate " " $ map (show . myFunc) ns
  where
    myFunc = (* 3) -- replace by your own function

getOneInt :: IO Int
getOneInt = read <$> getLine
```

Alternatively, if you want to eschew the `do` notation:

```
main =
    getOneInt                                        >>=
    flip replicateM getOneInt                        >>=
    putStrLn . intercalate " " . map (show . myFunc)
  where
    myFunc = (* 3) -- replace by your own function
```

Comment: Not neccessarily the requested one-liner, but structured nicely. I think I'll take this to start with. Many thanks.

Comment: So if I got you correctly it's not possible to read numbers from stdin without that extra function getOneInt as Dogbert stated in his comment?

Comment: @Hennes You could just use `read <$> getLine :: IO Int` instead. However, since it's used in multiple places of the code, it makes sense to define a `getOneInt` function.